# MKMapView not loading to my specified position

Tags: ios

I have an MKMapView on my storyboard and when i go to the storyboard just a default view loads not the specifications have set lat and long and span but doesnt zoom to the location im looking for.

[image]

here is .h

```
//
//  ContactViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;

@end
```

here is .m

```
//
//  ContactViewController.m


#import "ContactViewController.h"


@interface ContactViewController ()

@end

// define long and lat of location
#define map_long 42.877391;
#define map_lat -80.734766;

// define span
#define map_span 0.05f;



@implementation ContactViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //[super viewDidLoad];

    MKCoordinateRegion myregion;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mycenter;

    mycenter.latitude = map_lat;
    mycenter.longitude = map_long;

    MKCoordinateSpan myspan;
    myspan.latitudeDelta = map_span;
    myspan.longitudeDelta = map_span;


    myregion.center = mycenter;
    myregion.span = myspan;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [myMapView setRegion:myregion animated:YES];
    [myMapView setCenterCoordinate:mycenter animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Comment: The `map_long` and `map_lat` constant values seem to be backwards (unless you really meant to go to Antarctica).  `map_long` should be -80.xxx and `map_lat` should be 42.xxx.  Unrelated but you should not have a `;` at the end of those #defines.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning anything to `myCenter` .

You should be creating your region with something like:

```
 MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(yourCenterCoord, 250, 250);
```

(where the first parameter is your `CLLocationCoordinate2D` center variable and the other two are latitude and longitude distance from center)